# How do I know the readAheadLimit for a BufferedReader?

Tags: java, parsing, bufferedreader, file-format

I am using a `BufferedReader` in Java to parse a specific file format.

The files look something like this:

```
HEADING_ONE
1
3
4.5
2
HEADING_TWO
2
6
etc...
```

So, I am using the following code to parse this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
String line = "";
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.startsWith("HEADING_ONE")) {
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            // Do something with the line, which is now a number
        }
    else if (line.startsWith("HEADING_TWO")) {
        while... // The same as above
    }
}
```

But this code has an issue with it - the inner while loops eat the next line HEADING line. So after the first HEADING parse, the program breaks down.

It is for this reason that I wish to use `mark()` and `reset()`. I modified the code so that the *inner* while loop looks something like:

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.contains("HEADING")) {
        br.reset();
        break;
    } else {
        // Do something with the line, which is now a number.
    }
    br.mark(???)
}
```

This works by marking the location of the last line. If the parser encounters a new heading line, it backs up the `BufferedReader` to that location.

However, `mark()` takes an argument called `readAheadLimit` which is a

> Limit on the number of characters that may be read while still
>   preserving the mark. An attempt to reset the stream after reading
>   characters up to this limit or beyond may fail. A limit value larger
>   than the size of the input buffer will cause a new buffer to be
>   allocated whose size is no smaller than limit. Therefore large values
>   should be used with care.

Is there any way to know in advance the size of the `readAheadLimit` in this particular case? Or do I calculate the length of the largest heading and use that as a value? Or should I enforce some sort of line limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Scanner` class was created to solve these kinds of problems. Your code rewritten to use Scanner would look like:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(reader);
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    if (line.startsWith("HEADING_ONE")) {
        while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            int i = scanner.nextInt(); 
            // do something with int
            // skip to next line
            scanner.nextLine();
        }
    } else if (line.startsWith("HEADING_TWO")) {
        while... // The same as above
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a minor problem with the `nextInt` method though: it only reads the integer, leaving the line separator in the stream, so the next time you call `nextLine` you get an empty string... this can be fixed by calling `nextLine` when you are done reading the numbers, before reading the next heading.

Comment: Yeah, the ints are mostly for the example. I ended up using Scanner's `hasNext(Pattern pattern)` method which matches more accurately what I'm looking for.